# Internal server error - htaccess file lines that make me

Tags: .htaccess

I have a following set of lines in the downloaded folder, when opening in the htaccess fil, i found these lines on the htaccess file.

Is it related to wamp server, i newly installed in my localhost.

```
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    <FilesMatch ".(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|swf|css|js|txt)$">
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 1 day"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* ./index.php
```

**Apache error log**

```
[Tue Mar 17 14:33:05.181448 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6608:tid 528] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 17 14:33:05.182449 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6608:tid 528] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Tue Mar 17 14:33:05.182449 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6608:tid 528] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Tue Mar 17 14:33:05.186454 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6608:tid 528] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5336
[Tue Mar 17 14:33:05.800324 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5336:tid 448] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Mar 17 14:33:07.423483 2015] [core:alert] [pid 5336:tid 960] [client ::1:56548] C:/wamp/www/smart/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

what is these mean and can you guys help me this

Thanks,

Comment: Can you tell me if it's using CRLF for new lines?

Comment: i am not sure, how can i find that

Comment: What editor you use? Some editors like notepad++ can show special characters.

Comment: yes i am using notepad++, but i dont find any special characters

Comment: **View** =>  **Show Symbols** =>  **Show All Characters**

Comment: Thanks, but i couldnt find any special characters

Comment: You have to take a look at your http servers error log file. That is where it tells you what the error is. Everything else is _guess work_, that does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks @arksscha these are the lines in the apache error log---  Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Tue Mar 17 14:33:07.423483 2015] [core:alert] [pid 5336:tid 960]
>   [client ::1:56548] C:/wamp/www/smart/.htaccess: Invalid command
>   'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a **module not
>   included** in the server configuration

Apache doesn't know what command that is because you have to enable the module. In order for most things to work in Apache the module has to be enabled. Now some are enabled by default and some aren't.

You need to edit your Apache config and uncomment the module_rewrite line.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```